# Loading layer from ComboBox in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, attribute-index

I made a plugin what has multiple combobox but i have problem with the information load from the second combobox it depends on the combobox 1st. 
In the first combo box, i can choose layers from the loaded ones.

```
    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer_list = []
    for layer in layers:
         layer_list.append(layer.name())

    self.dlg.reteg.addItems(layer_list)
```

And the problem is that, in the second combobox i want a list from the selected layer's attribute names.

Answer (score 2):

Just play with the signal `layerChanged` from [QgsMapLayerComboBox](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayerComboBox.html)

Below, you will find a simple example to get layer id with `layer.id()` when you change layer in `QgsMapLayerComboBox`. You could instead use the `setLayer` slot from [QgsFieldComboBox](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsFieldComboBox.html) to set the attributes you want to display in your second combobox (assuming you have both combo components `QgsMapLayerComboBox` and `QgsFieldComboBox`)

```
def print_layer_id(layer):
    print layer.id()
# I supposed reteg is the id of the QgsMapLayerComboBox
self.dlg.reteg.layerChanged.connect(print_layer_id)
```

Comment: Sorry, this is my first plugin i created, and I'm on a very amateur lvl in this, i made a variable to read the layer name selected in the 'reteg' named combobox, and  in layers it searching for the same name and select it, as active_vl, but the problem is, this is always be the first layer in the combobox list, after selecting an other the plugin dosn't refresh to the selected one.